# ichi-gatsu vs hitotsuki

Tags: word-choice, counters

Can some help me by explaining what the difference between these two is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[一月]{いちがつ} is "January".
[一月]{ひとつき} (or [一か月]{いっかげつ}) is "one month".

---

Compare:

[一月]{いちがつ}、[二月]{にがつ}、[三月]{さんがつ}... = January, February, March...
[一月]{ひとつき}、[二月]{ふたつき}、[三月]{みつき}... (or [一か月]{いっかげつ}、[二か月]{にかげつ}、[三か月]{さんかげつ}...) = one month, two months, three months...

Comment: （辞書を引いたらすぐわかるような気もしますが・・・）

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between 一月【いちがつ】 and 一月【ひとつき】.

一月【いちがつ】 means January, but 一月【ひとつき】 means month (one month).

For example:

> - 一月は寒い。 - It's cold in January. (Not one month)
> - 一月に一回髪を切る - I have my hair cut **once a month**.
>
>   - It can mean "I have my hair cut **in January**.

How to distinguish them - It's bit hard. ***Guess from the context***.

In order to distinguish them easily, you can write *ひと月*. (It is sometimes used)

Comment: If my answer is not helpful for you, I'm sorry. I haven't realized that you had already accepted the answer.

Comment: `How to distinguish them - It's bit hard. Guess from the context.` When listening talk, you can distinguish them from **pronunciation**.